# Can I reduce these lines of code make double key press to switch between two of if/else if options

Tags: c#, if-statement, refactoring

I would like to reduce this to the fewest possible lines of code.

This using C# code in Unity, but the question is more about basic refactoring. There is no timer yet, I'm simply trying to write code print timer started/timer stopped to the Unity console.

```
void Update()
    {
        pressSpacebar();
    }

void pressSpacebar()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            if(!timerIsRunning)
            {
                StartTimer();
            }
            else if (timerIsRunning)
            {
                StopTimer();
            }
        }
    }

    bool timerIsRunning;

    void StartTimer()
    {
        timerIsRunning = true;
        print("Timer Running");
//to check if bool changed (and not just the text)
        print(timerIsRunning);
    }

    void StopTimer()
    {
        timerIsRunning = false;
        print("Timer Stopped");
        print(timerIsRunning);

    }
```

Comment: Reducing the lines of code is only adviseable if it increases readability. Never reduced the Nr. of lines if it decreases readability. | That else..if makes no sense unless `timerIsRunning` is a nullable Bool, wich it is not | `pressSpacebar` really should be called "toggleTimer" or something like that. Maybe even all the way to a fully fledged command Then you could inlune the start and stop timer code. | You also should be adding the proper Unity tags, in case there is a better way all around.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code, but if it bothers you, you could introduce a method `ToggleTimer()` that switches the timer on if currently off, and vice versa, i.e. `if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) { ToggleTimer(); }`.

Comment: I actually had quite a bit of fun with that refactor.

Comment: `I would like to reduce this to the fewest possible lines of code.` => [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @xTwisteDx your *refactor* could be reduced more...but is an improvement overall. The problem with these kind of answers is it generates opinionated answers and of which is off topic unfortunately.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ yeh you're right about that. There are so many different ways to do things. Show me how much more it can be reduced from `Option 1` I'd love to see. I can see how it could be reduced by getting rid of the `TimerManager()` altogether but I am guessing that he's using it elsewhere. Also getting rid of the `if(input..)` and simply attaching an event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so for starters, I'd remove the `Update()` method because it merely calls `pressSpacebar()` which is pointless. Just call it directly wherever `Update()` is needed.
Also, I removed the `else if` because it's not needed. Either it returns true in the if statement then `break` or it doesn't. Removes lines of code, not sure if it's technically worth it. Finally, because your other methods don't do much in the way of making significant changes, I moved them inside of your `pressSpaceBar()` method, assuming that you don't need those other `StartTimer()` and `EndTimer()` elsewhere in code. In my example, I swapped out two methods for one that swaps and effectively does the same thing.

### Option 1: Methods StartTimer() and EndTimer() Not used elsewhere.

```
    void pressSpacebar()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
           //Source: @Enigmativity
           //Sets by using the not operator. Acts as a switch.
           timerIsRunning = !timerIsRunning;
           print(timerIsRunning);
        }
    }
```

### Option 2: Methods StartTimer() and EndTimer Are used elsewhere.

```
void pressSpacebar()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        TimerManager();
    }
}


//INFO: Replaced startTimer() & stopTimer() with this to switch.
void TimerManager()
{
    //Source: @Enigmativity
    //Sets by using the not operator. Acts as a switch.
    timerIsRunning = !timerIsRunning;
    print(timerIsRunning);
}
```

Comment: The "Most Extreme" could be more extreme - try `timerIsRunning = !timerIsRunning;` instead of the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

As thought experiment, I guess if you don't mind a bit string interpolation, and bitwise XOR, you can further reduce the amount of code to run your sample.

```
bool timerIsRunning;
void Update() // I'm leaving this unchanged as you might need to add more context here, otherwise, feel free to unline `pressSpacebar()` here and remove more lines
{
    pressSpacebar();
}
void pressSpacebar() {
   if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) 
       print($"Timer {((timerIsRunning ^= true) ? "Running" : "Stopped")}, {timerIsRunning}");
}
```

**Upd** oh, you also can drop squiggly brackets here too

Comment: Nice. Meets the criterion of "fewest possible lines of code". Who cares about lost readability, right?

Answer (score 0):

**Timerless solution**

A use case like this one does not require an actual timer. You can just keep track of the start time and measure the difference, which results in pretty simple code.

```
DateTime? _startTime;

void pressSpacebar()
{
    if (!Input.GetKeyDown("space")) return;

    if (_startTime.HasValue)
    {
        var duration = DateTime.Now - _startTime.Value;
        print("Timer ran for {0} seconds", duration.Seconds);
        _startTime = null;
    }
    else
    {
        _startTime = DateTime.Now;
        print("Timer started.");
    }
}
```

While this is not much shorter than your original code, it eliminates the need to add the timer code (that you hadn't added yet) which will hopefully make your overall solution both shorter and easier to understand.